# OPTION (MAXRECURSION X) in MERGE Statement with CTE not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have the following CTE (Microsoft SQL Server 2017) which is working as intended:

```
WITH DATE_CTE (Datum)
as
(
    SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(1970, 1, 1)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(Day, 1, DATE_CTE.Datum) FROM DATE_CTE WHERE YEAR(DATE_CTE.Datum) < 2100 
) 
SELECT DATE_CTE.Datum, 
        YEAR(DATE_CTE.Datum) as [Year], 
        MONTH(DATE_CTE.Datum) as [Month], 
        DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DATE_CTE.Datum) as IsoWeek, 
        CAST(YEAR(DATE_CTE.Datum) AS VARCHAR(4)) + IIF(MONTH(DATE_CTE.Datum) < 10, '0' + CAST(MONTH(DATE_CTE.Datum) AS VARCHAR(1)), CAST(MONTH(DATE_CTE.Datum) AS VARCHAR(2))) as YearMonth, 
        -1 as SelID,  
        CASE WHEN MONTH(DATE_CTE.Datum) = 1 AND DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DATE_CTE.Datum) >= 52 THEN YEAR(DATE_CTE.Datum)-1 WHEN MONTH(DATE_CTE.Datum) = 12 AND DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DATE_CTE.Datum) = 1 THEN YEAR(DATE_CTE.Datum)+1 ELSE YEAR(DATE_CTE.Datum) END as WeekYear
FROM DATE_CTE OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

This will return the following data (from 1970 till 2100 -> 47483 Data rows):

```
    Date       Year        Month       IsoWeek     YearMonth SelID       WeekYear
    ---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- --------- ----------- -----------
    1970-01-01 1970        1           1           197001    -1          1970
    1970-01-02 1970        1           1           197001    -1          1970
    1970-01-03 1970        1           1           197001    -1          1970
    1970-01-04 1970        1           1           197001    -1          1970
    1970-01-05 1970        1           2           197001    -1          1970
    1970-01-06 1970        1           2           197001    -1          1970
    1970-01-07 1970        1           2           197001    -1          1970
    1970-01-08 1970        1           2           197001    -1          1970
    1970-01-09 1970        1           2           197001    -1          1970
    1970-01-10 1970        1           2           197001    -1          1970
    ...
```

Now I'd like to save the data in a specific table which might have already some data in it (and even worse: might have some additional fields). So my idea was to use a merge statement like this:

```
WITH DATE_CTE (Datum)
as
(
    SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(1970, 1, 1)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(Day, 1, DATE_CTE.Datum) FROM DATE_CTE WHERE YEAR(DATE_CTE.Datum) < 2100 
) 
MERGE INTO SYS_LIST_DATEHLP AS Target  
USING (
        SELECT 
                DATE_CTE.Datum, 
                YEAR(DATE_CTE.Datum), 
                MONTH(DATE_CTE.Datum), 
                DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DATE_CTE.Datum), 
                CAST(YEAR(DATE_CTE.Datum) AS VARCHAR(4)) + IIF(MONTH(DATE_CTE.Datum) < 10, '0' + CAST(MONTH(DATE_CTE.Datum) AS VARCHAR(1)), 
                CAST(MONTH(DATE_CTE.Datum) AS VARCHAR(2))), 
                -1, 
                CASE WHEN MONTH(DATE_CTE.Datum) = 1 AND DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DATE_CTE.Datum) >= 52 THEN YEAR(DATE_CTE.Datum)-1 WHEN MONTH(DATE_CTE.Datum) = 12 AND DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DATE_CTE.Datum) = 1 THEN YEAR(DATE_CTE.Datum)+1 ELSE YEAR(DATE_CTE.Datum) END
        FROM DATE_CTE OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
       )  
       AS Source (SYS_DATE, SYS_YEAR, SYS_MONTH, [WEEK], KAPMONAT, SEL_ID, WEEKYEAR)  
    ON Target.SYS_DATE = Source.SYS_DATE  
WHEN MATCHED THEN  
    UPDATE SET SYS_YEAR = Source.SYS_YEAR, SYS_MONTH = Source.SYS_MONTH, [WEEK] = Source.[WEEK], KAPMONAT = Source.KAPMONAT, SEL_ID = Source.SEL_ID, WEEKYEAR = Source.WEEKYEAR
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  
    INSERT (SYS_DATE, SYS_YEAR, SYS_MONTH, [WEEK], KAPMONAT, SEL_ID, WEEKYEAR)
    VALUES (Source.SYS_DATE, Source.SYS_YEAR, Source.SYS_MONTH, Source.[WEEK], Source.KAPMONAT, Source.SEL_ID, Source.WEEKYEAR);
```

But this always fails with the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OPTION'.

Leaving out `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` is not an option, as the CTE makes far more than 100 recursions and then SQL just responds with:

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Where do  I have to set the `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` here? Is that even possible at all? Sadly I didn't find any mention of this "special" case in the Microsoft Docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query hints always go at the very end of the query. So just move the `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` to immediately before the final semi colon.

```
/* Rest of query omitted*/
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  
    INSERT (SYS_DATE, SYS_YEAR, SYS_MONTH, [WEEK], KAPMONAT, SEL_ID, WEEKYEAR)
    VALUES (Source.SYS_DATE, Source.SYS_YEAR, Source.SYS_MONTH, Source.[WEEK], Source.KAPMONAT, Source.SEL_ID, Source.WEEKYEAR)
     OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
    ;
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! I thought it might have something to do with the placement of OPTION(), but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table variable with the structure of your CTE to store results that will be used later in the `merge` statement:

```
declare @tmp table (
                        [Datum]     date, 
                        [Year]      int, 
                        [Month]     int,
                        [IsoWeek]   int, 
                        [YearMonth] int, 
                        [SelID]     int, 
                        [WeekYear]  int
                    )
```

Then you can execute your CTE with `MAXRECURSION 0` writing the results in the table variable:

```
WITH DATE_CTE (Datum)
as
(
    SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(1970, 1, 1)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(Day, 1, DATE_CTE.Datum) FROM DATE_CTE WHERE YEAR(DATE_CTE.Datum) < 2100 
) 
insert into @tmp
SELECT DATE_CTE.Datum, 
        YEAR(DATE_CTE.Datum) as [Year], 
        MONTH(DATE_CTE.Datum) as [Month], 
        DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DATE_CTE.Datum) as IsoWeek, 
        CAST(YEAR(DATE_CTE.Datum) AS VARCHAR(4)) + IIF(MONTH(DATE_CTE.Datum) < 10, '0' + CAST(MONTH(DATE_CTE.Datum) AS VARCHAR(1)), CAST(MONTH(DATE_CTE.Datum) AS VARCHAR(2))) as YearMonth, 
        -1 as SelID,  
        CASE WHEN MONTH(DATE_CTE.Datum) = 1 AND DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DATE_CTE.Datum) >= 52 THEN YEAR(DATE_CTE.Datum)-1 WHEN MONTH(DATE_CTE.Datum) = 12 AND DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DATE_CTE.Datum) = 1 THEN YEAR(DATE_CTE.Datum)+1 ELSE YEAR(DATE_CTE.Datum) END as WeekYear
FROM DATE_CTE OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Now you should be able to merge your table `SYS_LIST_DATEHLP` with table variable `@tmp`:

```
MERGE INTO SYS_LIST_DATEHLP AS Target  
USING (
        SELECT 
             [Datum]     
            ,[Year]     
            ,[Month]    
            ,[IsoWeek]  
            ,[YearMonth]
            ,[SelID]    
            ,[WeekYear] 
        FROM @tmp  
       )  
       AS Source (SYS_DATE, SYS_YEAR, SYS_MONTH, [WEEK], KAPMONAT, SEL_ID, WEEKYEAR)  
    ON Target.SYS_DATE = Source.SYS_DATE  
WHEN MATCHED THEN  
    UPDATE SET SYS_YEAR = Source.SYS_YEAR, SYS_MONTH = Source.SYS_MONTH, [WEEK] = Source.[WEEK], KAPMONAT = Source.KAPMONAT, SEL_ID = Source.SEL_ID, WEEKYEAR = Source.WEEKYEAR
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  
    INSERT (SYS_DATE, SYS_YEAR, SYS_MONTH, [WEEK], KAPMONAT, SEL_ID, WEEKYEAR)
    VALUES (Source.SYS_DATE, Source.SYS_YEAR, Source.SYS_MONTH, Source.[WEEK], Source.KAPMONAT, Source.SEL_ID, Source.WEEKYEAR);
```